# Instantiate IdentityManager in asp.net Identity MVC 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, simplemembership

VS 2013 does not recognize the IDentityManager class that will allow me to reset the password, how can I solve this problem, thank you.

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: **that is :** _IdentityManager.Passwords.GenerateResetPasswordToken_ and _IdentityManager.Passwords.ResetPassword_

Answer (score 0):

The [SimpleSecurity Project](http://simplesecurity.codeplex.com/) provides an example of how to handle password reset using ASP.NET Identity in MVC 5. Look at the [source code in the ***AccountController***](http://simplesecurity.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#AspNetIdentity/SimpleSecurity.AspNetIdentity.RefApp/Controllers/AccountController.cs) for the methods ***ResetPassword*** and ***ResetPasswordConfirmation***.